# What's the best way to configure LRU cache using open-resty lua scripts in nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, lua, openresty

I am using openresty lua (https://github.com/openresty) to configure our nginx proxy.  I have one main proxy.template that defines 3 locations, but want to use only one LRU cache for multiple process initialization calls (since they take so long and nothing else, that is why I am using a script).  I want to define a variable that can be passed into each location, but am pretty sure I am not doing this correctly.  I have:

```
  #init_by_lua_file $lru_cache /etc/scripts/lua/process_cache.lua;

  location /process {
      access_by_lua_file /etc/scripts/lua/process_access.lua;

      proxy_set_header Content-Type "application/json";
      proxy_set_header Accept "application/json";

      proxy_ssl_server_name      on;

      proxy_pass $target;
  }

  location /process/init {
      set_by_lua_file $lru_cache /etc/scripts/lua/process_cache.lua;

      add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers set-cookie;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers set-cookie;

      access_by_lua_file /etc/scripts/lua/process_init.lua;
  }
```

The process_cache creates the cache (one per proxy startup) and I would like it to be referenced by the process_init.lua and process_access.lua which do different things.  For example, process_init is only called once for a UI initialization and establishes the specific cache entries, process_access checks to make sure the entry hasn't expired and if not uses it, otherwise creates a new entry, so that a long call to another server is not needed.

The above would require the lru_cache variable to be passed amongst the two locations.  My latest attempts were in the area of trying to place process_cache.lua within the /process/init path, but then it just gets initialized each time, so starting with an empty cache each /process/init call is useless.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider ngx.shared ?
You can specific exptime for your strings.

: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict ?

Comment: Yes, I have started looking at this approach this morning, since there does not seem any other reasonable solution, since global variables across workers is not really supported.  Shared memory/dictionary just seems a bit kludgy to use in each location to get a reference to my lru cache.  Let you know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately shared dictionary does not support memory references to a cache.  Nor can it be used in the sense of a cache for our purposes, since we would like to maintain all the functions of the openresty lru cache without sacrificing anything.

Comment: Due to the scope of my requirement and the exptime that dict items can have I found this to be an acceptable solution for a second level cache.